# Android Studio - automatically load support libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I'm getting frustrated with having to load the same support libraries over and over again each time I start a new project. Is there to make sure they're always loaded when starting Android Studio?

Thanks.

Comment: Did any of the responses helped you?

Answer (score 0):

[Edit] I just found a library from jack wharton doing what you are looking for. Check SDK Manager Plugin : https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin

It exists for some libraries. You have to check on building your projects with [Graddle](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/) in Android-Studio :

[Tips for Graddle](http://www.alonsoruibal.com/my-gradle-tips-and-tricks/)
[App generator with included libraries](http://velcro.andrewreitz.com)

Graddle Test project that loads it automatically (for example only)

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+'
  }
}

// Manifest version information!
def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 0

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:20.+'

  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
def buildTime = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))

android {
  compileSdkVersion 20
  buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 20

    versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
    versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"

    buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\""
    buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${buildTime}\""
  }

  signingConfigs {
    release {
      storeFile file(storeFilePath)
      storePassword keystorePassword
      keyAlias storeKeyAlias
      keyPassword aliasKeyPassword
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    debug {
      applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
      versionNameSuffix '-dev'
    }

    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }

  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set Android Studio to work offline if have loaded the supported libraries once;
Open **Setting** menu and search **Gradle** as keywords check on the **Offline work** :

[image]

[image]

Do remember to uncheck the checkbox if you have changed the your dependency in **build.gradle**